# How to redirect from an ajax request given that I need to render the page sever side from data I pass via ajax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is JavaScript on my page that is trying to redirect the user to /editUpload after it renders on the server given the data that's passed to it:

```
function editUpload(id) {
    id = {
        "id": id
    }
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            document.html = xmlHttp.responseText; //What should this line be?
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", '/editUpload', true); // true for asynchronous
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    var dataAsJson = JSON.stringify(id);
    xmlHttp.send(dataAsJson);
}
```

This is how the server responds to that request:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    //do stuff with id
    res.render('editUpload', {thingIDidWithId: data}); //or should this be return res.render('editUpload'); ?
});
```

**I know that I could instead call `window.location = '/editUpload?=id'`**

`xmlHttp.responseText` is returning the correct html, I want that to be the html of the page after the ajax call returns.

Comment: When you're effectively reloading the page, why don't you reload it like you already suggested?

Comment: If your Ajax call returns just the body HTML you want, you can do document.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText.  But, if you want a whole page reloaded, including all the scripts and CSS from the `<head>` section, then `window.location = '/editUpload?=id'` is likely more appropriate as you suggested and that is what query parameters in the URL are for.

Comment: You're right, I need those scripts and CSS. Darn.